# Mark executed lines in Visual Studio while debugging

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Is there any tool in Visual Studio (or a plugin) which would mark every line of code that executed? I imagine how it would work:

1. Switch to Debug Mode
2. Press a button to start capturing lines
3. Execute some code
4. Pause/stop capturing lines
5. See every line that executed (and therefore which methods or `if` statements were omitted) as highlighted in the beginning of each line

Comment: That's what IntelliTrace does